# What's the role of hashcode in the java object header

Tags: java, jvm-hotspot

There are 25 bits in the object header to identify the hashcode when a lock is in the state of lock-free. I would like to know the usefulness of hashcode.

Comment: What have you researched so far? What specific part is unclear?

Comment: I think people completely misunderstand this question. The OP is asking about Java object header, not something which is part of the language definition, but rather of the HotSpot architecture, so not asking about the general purpose of hashcode, but why it is used in an object header.

Comment: I agree with RealSkeptic and have therefore added a tag to make the question relevant to the HotSpot architecture, since the tag "java" on its own is just for general Java language questions.

Comment: `System.identityHashCode(…)` is guaranteed to always return the same value for the same object, hence, once it has been used, the value has to be remembered for the object. People often think, this identity hash code was a memory address, but the HotSpot JVM has a generational garbage collector which may move objects in the heap memory. Further, the predictability of memory addresses in a local allocation buffer makes addresses bad hash codes (in terms of `HashMap` efficiency). So, there are different possible algorithms for generating it, but the result must be stored in the object header.

Comment: That is amazing! I gave a wrong questing.But you fix it and gave the correct answer.
I have understood it. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

This is an implementation detail, as such the true definition is in the source code, for example [these comments](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/hotspot/file/87ee5ee27509/src/share/vm/oops/markOop.hpp) should explain some of those details.

The default `hashCode` has 25 bits for a `32-bit` VM (no idea where you got the `23` from) and `31` for a `64-bit` VM.

I *guess* by lock-free state you mean biased locking, but it's either one or the other, not both at the same time, because simply there is no space in the mark work for both.

The usefulness is the same (whatever you mean by that) - it's just that since there are less bits there are higher collisions expected.

Comment: Yes,you are right. I have correct the question description.Thank you.